# Chart.js add custom title, subtitle, graphics

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

I'm using Chart.js for a project (http://www.chartjs.org/).

Does somebody know how to draw on the actual canvas new stuff, like a title or add custom images, add 'margin' to the chart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

[image]

You can set ChartJs's `onAnimationComplete` callback to call your custom drawing code when ChartJs has completed it's own drawing and animating.

In that callback you can get the `canvas context` (== the same canvas/context that you originally fed into ChartJS) and use that context to draw whatever new custom content you desire.

Here's an example of how it works:

[Inserting percentage charts.js doughnut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499475/inserting-percentage-charts-js-doughnut/28506118#28506118)

ChartJS does not have a native "padding" to its chart content. One way to get some padding is to draw the chart to a smaller in-memory canvas and then draw that in-memory canvas to your visible canvas with an offset to allow for your desired padding.

Here's a example:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var pieData = [
  {
    value: 200,
    color:"#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red"
  },
  {
    value: 50,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
    label: "Green"
  },
  {
    value: 100,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870",
    label: "Yellow"
  },
  {
    value: 40,
    color: "#949FB1",
    highlight: "#A8B3C5",
    label: "Grey"
  },
  {
    value: 120,
    color: "#4D5360",
    highlight: "#616774",
    label: "Dark Grey"
  }

];

// create an in-memory canvas (c) 
var c = document.createElement("canvas");

// size it to your desired size (without padding)
c.width=100;
c.height=100;

// make it hidden
c.style.visibility='hidden';
document.body.appendChild(c);

// create the chart on the in-memory canvas
var cctx = c.getContext("2d");
window.myPie = new Chart(cctx).Pie(pieData,{
  responsive:false,
  animation:false,


  // when the chart is fully drawn,
  // draw the in-memory chart to the visible chart
  // allowing for your desired padding
  // (this example pads 100 width and 50 height
  onAnimationComplete:function(){
    ctx.drawImage(c,100,50);
    ctx.fillText('Space to add something here with 50x100 padding',5,20);
    ctx.fillText('Added Padding',5,90);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,100);
    ctx.lineTo(100,100);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Ah! You mean *padding* not margin. ChartJS does not have a native padding to its chart content, but I've added a workaround to may answer. Good luck with your project!